# Clearing array reference in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have created a values[] array which consist of integers. Then, I have copied the array reference to scores[]. After some operations, how can I remove the reference from scores[] so that I can only access my array with values[]?`int[] scores = {3, 5, 8};
int[] values = scores;`

Comment: Show your code so we can suggest changes

Comment: `scores = null;` maybe?

Comment: You can assign a null `scores = null`, to dereference!

Comment: Note, Java coding style says that you should declare as `int[] array`, not `int array[]`.

Comment: I thought that null should erase the the array but {scores = null;} worked and the array still exists in values reference. Then, if there is another reference to an array, we cannot remove the array only with one reference?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question you are asking is given two variables that each point to the same array (scores and values), how do you make it such that values is the only variable pointing to the array? You simply need to assign a different value to scores. I don't know if you care what the value of scores is after this operation is completed, but one thing you could do is:

```
scores = <Literally anything except "scores" (eg. null)>;
```

This will cause the variable scores to no longer point at the same array. If you want to maintain the value of scores while deleting the pointer to the array, the way to do this is to copy scores into itself.

```
scores = Arrays.copyOf(scores, scores.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer